# What is difference between declared-services and service in manifest.yml?

Tags: python, django, cloud-foundry

In the `manifest.yml` for a django application deployed on cloud foundry PaaS, I can see there are two labels for services: `declared-services` and `services`. I want to know what is the difference and, for an Oracle database, which is the actual service bound?

```
 declared-services:
   oracle_db:
      label: oracle-ods
      plan: shared-nr
 services:
    - applogger
    - oracle_ods
    - odsui-kerberos-sso
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `services` tag in an application's manifest.yml file indicates to the Cloud Foundry CLI what services should be bound to the application for this manifest.

In your example, it would make sure that three services are bound and the names of those services would be `applogger`, `oracle_ods` and `odsui-kerberos-sso`. Those service must exists as the cf cli will not provision them for you.

I do not believe `declared_services` is an official property supported by the cf cli. It's not documented at the link below (at least not at the time I write this), where all the officially supported properties are documented.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html

I suppose that it's possible that there is something else reading and using the application's manifest.yml file, but it's not a standard part of Cloud Foundry. For example, it could be some provider specific extension or alternate cli that uses this property. If it is a provider specific extension, you'd need to confirm with the provider what it does.

Hope that helps!

Comment: `declared_services` appears to be an IBM BlueMix specific extension to the standard CF manifest file format.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. i tried removing declared_services tag and re push the application. It is working fine. i guess it is redundant tag maybe someone copied.